# woocommerce add to cart safari not working

Tags: wordpress, safari, woocommerce

http://ohri.srihari.guru

when I add to cart any of the event packages, which are the products, it works as planned in all browsers except for safari.

WHY does this happen?? I've tried installing a jquery cookie fixer from the woothemes support site to no avail...

safari is pretty critical for purchasing considering the high proportion of iOS users.

any help would be greatly appreciated... i've scoured the wordpress forums and woothemes forums and haven't found much. I even contacted my host @digitalocean support and they sent me a less than helpful response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all sorts of things to fix this and wasn't sure how, ultimately the issue was because I was using DNS forwarding with masking, and the links to external sites were not being addressed properly. i.e. my site was hosted at http://123.456.789/index.html but was masked to run at http://somewebSite.com/index.html. When i entered http://123.456.789/index.html in the browser clicking on those same links resulted in no X-frame-origins issues in the JS console, but running http://somewebSite.com/index.html did. In order to properly mask I had to add my host's DNS name servers to my domain service, i.e. godaddy.com should have name servers of example, ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com, if since I was using digitalocean.com as my hosting service. Changing the base site URL under settings/general in the WP dashboard maintained the root domain redirect in the address bar instead of showing the ip address.